# Bootstrap elements resize after Kendo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

After adding Kendo UI to my ASP.NET MVC project, I've figured out my forms elements are bigger, including font size and input elements.

I've uninstalled Kendo but my forms are still cluttered.

Do you have any idea where this problem might be from and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalled Kendo, all the css and related installed files must have to remove from your project, may be your browser caches some css file or some of the kendo css files are still attached in your project.